# Kubectl generate pod with same name all time

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubectl

I am new to kubernetes. Is there anyway we can fix the name of pod ?   If we are creating only one replica, then I want to be generated with same name all time. It's generating different name all time. If I want to see the logs of a container, each time I need to change the command with the newly generated pod name.

Following is sample of YAML file.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nagendra-app-deploy1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nagendra-app-deploy1
      labels:
        app: nagendra-app-deploy1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nagendra-spring-app1
        image: springbootapp:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      - name: nagendra-myImage
        image: myImage:v2
```

Comment: Use a StatefulSet instead. That will result in the pod being named the same.

Comment: How I can do that? Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Documentation for StatefulSet can be found at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

Comment: Hi, If you want to check the logs of the pods, you can just run the command with deployment name, for example `kubectl logs -f deployment/DEPLOY_NAME`. In your case it would be `kubectl logs -f deployment/nagendra-app-deploy1`

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to generate the same name for a deployment produced pod. as far as the command is concerned, you can use `kubectl get po -l app=nagendra-app-deploy1 -o jsonpath={.items[0].metadata.name}` to get the pod's name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and putting your thoughts here.

Comment: or use: `kubectl get pod -l app=nagendra-app-deploy1 | awk 'FNR==2 {print $1}'` if theres only one instance

Answer (score 1):

Here is the trick, I use to get the logs of the deployment

`kubectl logs -f  $(kubectl get deployment -o name | grep DEPLOYMENT_NAME | head -n 1)`

for example, in your situation, I just need to change deployment_name which is quite static.

`kubectl logs -f  $(kubectl get deployment -o name | grep nagendra-app-deploy1 | head -n 1)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don need a deployment (no need for rolling updates, no replica set that watches if the pod is up) you can simple deploy a pod.

A simple pod will keep it's name through the updates.